# Geopy distance between locations

Tags: python, google-maps, geopy, geographic-distance

I am using `geopy` for calculating distance between two locations.

```
from geopy.distance import distance
loc1 = (41.49008, -71.312796)
loc2 = (41.499498, -81.695391)
dist = distance(loc1,loc2).miles
print dist
```

this gives an output

> 538.390445157

But I just wanted to tally if the `geopy` calculations were close enough to google maps or not. So I checked it on google maps and its saying

> 638 miles

for the same locations.

How do I fill the difference?
Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Are you looking for the straight line distance or the driving distance?

Comment: i'm looking for driving distance

Comment: You will need to use the Google Directions Service or Distance Matrix Service for Driving distances (if you want them to compare to Google Maps)

Answer (score 2):

`geopy` calculates the straight-line distance while the 638 miles from Google maps is for traveling on roads. The 638 miles are for a route via I-80 W. Taking I-90 W, you need to drive 667 miles.